# MS Access 2016 - New field, data type 'number'. Why can I only see 'Long Integer' option not 'Single' or 'Double'

Tags: database, ms-access, office365

I am trying to add a new field to a MS Access database table. The field is a 'Number' data type. In the options beneath this I would like to change the "Field Size" setting from 'Long Integer' to 'Single' or 'Double', but these options are not available (only 'Long Integer' is). I have done this many times before, just not in this version of Access.

I am using MS Access 2016 part of Office365

[Screenshot show issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwblQ.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the screenshot, so that it shows the dropdown list of "Field Size"?

Comment: It is difficult to screen capture this. However i can assure you the only option in there is 'Long Integer'

Comment: Is this an Access App?

Comment: Not as far as I know (I am quite sure no). I just created a blank database using Access 2016 running on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new known error in Access 2016 see link

[Microsoft Link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/access-2016-data-type-number-field-size-drop-down/39d561fc-0161-420f-909c-a57f2031e7b4?page=1)

Alternatively, the only workaround currently is DDL, ie

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyNumber Double;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you create a basic table with just one field e.g. ID and Autonumber then save the table and view it as a data sheet.  Now in the Add New Field in the next column enter a number like 2.5. If you now go back to design view you will see that the field has been saved as Double general number.